# Find the volume of the solid generated when the region enclosed..

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the solid generated when the region enclosed 
$$y= \sqrt {x+1},\ y= \sqrt {2x},\  y=0$$ 
is revolved about the $x$-axis.

I found that both curves only have one intersection at $x=1$. How can I proceed then?

Comment: The $y=0$ may be a typo for the $y$-axis, that is, $x=0$.

Comment: nope, it is meant to be y=0, from my worksheet

Comment: The two curves and $y=0$ enclose a region which, when rotated, has infinite volume.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed the following colored are is supposed to revolve about $x$ axis.:

[image]

$x=1$ gives $y=\sqrt{2}$, so we have $$V=2\pi\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{2}}y(x_2-x_1)dy$$ where $y^2-1=x_2,~~\frac{y^2}{2}=x_1$.